# How can I create a Flatlist video with React Native?

Tags: react-native, youtube, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to achieve this look [videolist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMm5O.jpg). An image and a tile then once the user click on one of them it will open a video from Youtube.

Here is what I have. I do not know if I am going in the right way.

```
const VideoData = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: 'This is a title',
    url:
      'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZpxCRmfqY',
    image:
      '../imag3',
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'This is a title',
    url:
      'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZpxCRmfqY',
    image:
      '../image2',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'This is a title',
    url:
      'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZpxCRmfqY',
    image:
      '../image1',
  },
];
```

I do not need the style. I am just trying to figure out how to display my Youtube videos